# Whatsapp API (#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params

Tags: message, whatsapp, payload

I created below template in Whatsapp API. And I want to set the parameter value in the API call. What is the correct payload ? I have been following the Meta docs and trying but every time I get error. Please Help.

**Template:**

> You order # {{1}}  is received successfully.

[image]

**I used this payload:**

```
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp", 
"to": "918456712349", 
"type": "template", 
"template": { 
    "name": "order_notification",
    "language": { 
        "code": "en_US" 
    }
},
"components": [
    {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "135345345"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**But I am still getting this error**

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 132000,
    "error_data": {
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "details": "body: number of localizable_params (0) does not match the expected number of params (1)"
    },
    "error_subcode": 2494002,
    "fbtrace_id": "AzPa-uWXctIcdNVu0Lf3Fic"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

The issue due to closing the template object then opening a new component object.
make the component object inside the template object and it will be fixed

```js
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp", 
"to": "918456712349", 
"type": "template", 
"template": { 
    "name": "order_notification",
    "language": { 
        "code": "en_US" 
    }

"components": [
    {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "135345345"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
}
```

Comment: yes your answer is correct. In case of One time passwords, is the code (otp) itself is generated by us or by WhatsApp/Meta?

Answer (score 1):

change in parameter type "header", this code run for me:

```
 {
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp", 
    "to": "918456712349", 
    "type": "template", 
    "template": { 
        "name": "order_notification",
        "language": { 
            "code": "en_US" 
        },
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "xxxxxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, I changed my parameter structure as below:

```
            $parameters = [
                "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
                "recipient_type" => "individual",
                "to" => $phone,
                "type" => "template",
                "template" => [
                    "name" => "otp_code",
                    "language" => ["code" => "en"],
                    "components" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "body",
                            "parameters" => [
                                ["type" => "text", "text" => $message],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"to": "+919745270094",
"type": "template",
"template": {
"name": "otp_dibiz",
"language": {
"code": "en_US"
}
},
"components": [
{
"type": "body",
"parameters": [
{
"type": "text",
"text": "123456"
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: Its because of the request json body provided in documentation is not proper. This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the right answer of Hisham A, that if you have more than one param/variable as I did you just have to add as many elements to the component as params.

In my case (sorry text being in portuguese):

For the mensage body:

```
Reserva de {{1}} para o(s) dia(s) {{2}} de {{3}} para a carrinha {{4}}.
```

The json data:

```
{ 
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
 "to": "351934566644",
 "type": "template",
 "template": { 
    "name": "reserva_feita_teste",
    "language": { "code": "pt_PT" }, 
  
    "components": [
      {
          "type": "body",
          "parameters": [
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "Sofia"
              },
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "1, 2, 3"
              },
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "janeiro"
              },
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "Grande Nova"
              }
          ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

}

Answer (score -4):

Looks like the template is expecting 1 parameter, which is not being provided.

You can look at the documentation and example [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#send-a-whatsapp-message-using-a-template).

It includes a working example.

Comment: I am using Whatsapp Meta (Facebook) API. Not the Twilio API.

Comment: I have prepared the payload as per this docs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates
 If I use a template that does not have any variables than there is no issue. Only for the case where I am using any variable in a template, than I get this error. I am not sure what is the correct payload for this scenario.