(#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params
I can't figure out the issue,
I created a plain template for a sinlge language, it works. Then I added just one variable {{1}}.. and the api response Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "to": phoneNumber,  // Use phone number from Airtable
        "type": "template",
        "template": { "name": "statement_available_2", "language": { "code": "es" } },
        "components": [
        {
            "type": "body",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Your dynamic text here"  
                }
            ]}]

I really don't understand where the issue is

if you have added variable then while sending template you need to pass the parameter for that variable to replace .

the same question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322149/whatsapp-api-132000-number-of-parameters-does-not-match-the-expected-number-o
